# Subtracting two characters

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, strcmp

I just started programming in assembly so I am a beginner.

To practice, I am trying to rewrite a basic libc in assembly (NASM Intel syntax).

But I'm stuck on the *strcmp* function:

```
;; Compare two C-style NUL-terminated strings
;; Inputs   :  ESI = address of s1, EDI = address of s2
;; Outputs  :  EAX = return an integer less than, equal to, or greater than zero if s1 is found, respectively, to be less than, to match, or be greater than s2
strcmp:
    call strlen
    mov ecx, eax ; ecx = length of the string in esi

    repe cmpsb
    sub esi, edi ; result = *esi - *edi
    
    mov eax, esi
    
    ret
```

For me, it should work like this:

```
s1 db 'Hello World', 0
s2 db 'Hello Stack', 0
```

After the `repe cmpsb` instruction, `ESI` should be equal to `[s1 + 7]` and `EDI` to `[s2 + 7]`.

So I just have to do `EAX` = 'W' - 'S' = 87 - 83 = 4

The problem is, it doesn't work. I think the problem is that when I execute this instruction:

```
sub esi, edi ; result = *esi - *edi
```

I don't think that it means: *subtract the characters pointed to by `EDI` and `ESI`*.

Does anyone have an idea on how I can do this?

Comment: Have you ensured that `strlen` preserves the contents of `edi` and `esi`?  Also, note that `sub esi, edi` computes the difference of `edi` and `esi`, not the difference of the characters these two point to.

Comment: Also, what calling convention do you follow?  This looks a lot like the amd64 SysV ABI, but you seem to be writing 32 bit code for which this ABI is usually not used.

Comment: Thanks for answering me, I'm not sure. I am compiling for 32 bit Linux systems. So it's probably System V ABI i386. Do you have any idea on how I can compute the difference of the characters rather than the registers? (and yes strlen preserves the content of EDI and ESI)

Comment: If you are writing 32 bit code, the standard ABI passes arguments through the stack.  However, this is only relevant if you intend to interface with C code.  If all code is written by yourself in assembly, you can use whatever ABI you want.  Let me write an answer to your question then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is almost correct.  There are three issues left:

- you should not assume that `strcmp` preserves the contents of `esi` and `edi` unless you have explicitly specified that it does so.  It's very easy to later change `strcmp` and then forget about the requirement, leading to all sorts of annoying problems.
- instead of returning the difference between `*edi` and `*esi`, you return the difference between `edi` and `esi`.  Also, as `cmpsb` advances `esi` and `edi` by one, the last characters compared are found at `edi[-1]` and `esi[-1]`.
- you have an off-by-one error: `strlen` returns the number of characters that preceed the NUL byte, but you do need to compare the NUL byte as well.  Otherwise, you'll end up finding that two strings are equal if one is a prefix of the other since you never check that the second string actually ends when the first one does.

To fix the first issue, I recommend you to save and restore `esi` and `edi` around the call to `strlen`.  The easiest way to do so is to push them on the stack:

```
    push esi             ; save ESI and EDI
    push edi
    call strlen          ; compute the string length
    pop  edi             ; restore ESI and EDI
    pop  esi
```

The second issue is fixed by loading the characters to compare from memory, computing the difference, and then storing the result to `eax`:

```
    movzx eax, byte [esi-1] ; load byte from ESI[-1] and zero extend into EAX
    movzx ecx, byte [edi-1] ; load byte from EDI[-1] and zero extend into ECX
    sub   eax, ecx          ; compute the difference
```

This also addresses the third issue by using the correct offsets right away.  Note that `movzx` is needed here instead of the slightly simpler

```
    mov   al, [esi-1]       ; load byte from ESI[-1] into AL
    sub   al, [edi-1]       ; subtract EDI[-1] from AL
```

since we want the result of the subtraction to be correctly sign-extended into `eax`.

Comment: I really thank you for taking the time to help me, it works perfectly now, again a big thank you !